# CMake won't build without set_source_files_properties with LANGUAGE CXX

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a small library that I have made (mostly wrappers for a more obtuse library underneath) which I have been compiling and using no problem in a contained project. I am now using this library in another project and have attempted to change the CMakeLists.txt appropriately (see below).

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

set(project "foobar")

project(${project} LANGUAGES CXX)

set(${project}_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(${project}_VERSION_MINOR 1)

add_library(${project} SHARED
./driver/foo.h
./driver/foo.c
./bar.cpp
./bar.hpp)

set_source_files_properties(./driver/foo.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)

target_compile_features(${project}
  PUBLIC
  cxx_std_11)

target_include_directories(${project} PUBLIC ./driver/ .)

 set_target_properties(${project} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

add_executable(bno055-test
./testingProject.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(test ${project})

install(
  TARGETS ${project}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

The error I have encountered is with the line `set_source_files_properties(./driver/foo.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)`.  When it comes to compiling this C file with the C++ flag above I get many warnings of the type `clang-8: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]`. This is expected, as I am using deprecated methods and should not be compiling this file using the C++ flag. However, whenever I remove this line, or alter it to specify C instead of C++, my *entire* project no longer builds and fails with error:

```
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
Makefile:283: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
"/usr/bin/make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

I'm not familiar enough with CMake to see why this line of code and error are related like this. Is there some alternative piece of code I should include to create the missing variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT`?

I assume that when I initially created this project using Eclipse this line was automatically generated and I am unclear as to why it now creates a problem when I had been compiling these files with the same CMakeLists.txt before (without library linking).

This is with clang@8.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help would be much appreciated! Apologies if I have missed something simple!

Comment: Perhaps use `project(${project} LANGUAGES C CXX)` to also enable C?

Comment: Extension of the file `foo.c` suggests that this is a C file, not a C++ one. If you want to compile it as C, enable C language in the `project()` call, like previous commenter suggested. With `set_source_files_properties` called with `LANGUAGE CXX` you tell CMake, that given file should be compiled as C++ one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there some alternative piece of code I should include to create the missing variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT`?

No, as the CMake error states, this is an "*internal CMake variable*" which should be initialized by CMake. It is not something you should have to set yourself. It should be set indirectly when you call `project()`. However, you only tell CMake you are using C++ (with [`CXX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#options) option) in the `project()` command. If you want CMake to make use of C and C++, you need to add both:

```
project(${project} LANGUAGES C CXX)
```

Even better, CMake enables C and C++ by default, so you can simply do:

```
project(${project})
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer cleared things up for me completely!